# Sorting using helper function - can the helper function return more than one variable?

Tags: python, sorting, return

I have two lists: `numbers` and `group`. I used a helper function to sort the list. What I want to know, is it possible to return another variable say, 'sorted'= 'True' from the function?

```
numbers = [8, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6]
group = [2, 3, 5, 7]

def sort_priority(values, group):
    sorted = 'False'
    def helper(x):
        if x in group:
            sorted = 'True' 
            return (0, x)
        else:
            return (1, x)

    values.sort(key=helper)
    return sorted
```

Comment: I don't clearly understand what you mean by 'another variable'. Do you mean another type? Do you mean return multiple variables?

Comment: I need to return true if 'if' condition satisfied. ie, sorted based on the helper function

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 3, you can achieve this with the [nonlocal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal) statement:

```
def sort_priority(values, group):
    sorted = 'False'
    def helper(x):
        nonlocal sorted
        if x in group:
            sorted = 'True'
            return (0, x)
        else:
            return (1, x)    
    values.sort(key=helper)
    return sorted
```

This allows the `sorted` variable in the outer scope to be modified by the inner scope of the helper function - so `sort_priority` will then return `"True"`.

If you're using Python 2, the `nonlocal` statement isn't available, but something similar can be achieved like this:

```
def sort_priority(values, group):
    nonlocals = {'sorted': 'False'}
    def helper(x):
        if x in group:
            nonlocals['sorted'] = 'True'
            return (0, x)
        else:
            return (1, x)    
    values.sort(key=helper)
    return nonlocals['sorted']
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @ekhumoro is probably what you want.

Another way, taking advantage of the fact that in Python,
functions are objects / first-class-citizens:

```
numbers = [8, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6]
group = [2, 3, 5, 7]

def sort_priority(values, group):
    def helper(x):
        if x in group:
            helper.wasSorted = 'True'
            return (0, x)
        else:
            return (1, x)
    helper.wasSorted = 'False'

    values.sort(key=helper)
    return helper.wasSorted

print(sort_priority(numbers, group))
```

Also, 'sorted' is the name of a built-in function,
which can cause some confusion
(so changed it to 'wasSorted').